# Keep custom fix in a plugin

Tags: plugins

I have a plugin that needs a (very) custom feature, for a site I'm making.
I've found it in the code, where I can remove some lines of code, so the feature is accessible as I would like. But I'm not sure how to maintain this custom fix in the future.

There is no hook for the fix.

#### Problems

- If the plugin is updated, then the fix will disappear.
- If I download the plugin and commit it to my repository, then I'll have a snapshot of what the fix was, but it's not a good way to maintain it.
- I'm not sure if it's possible to 'freeze' a plugin, so it cannot be updated. But even if that was possible, then that's obviously also error-prone.

Are there any good ways to get this done?

#### Further elaboration

It's a permission thing, where a custom user type, with very fewer capabilities, to be able to access a function (downloading a package slip).

So what I do is that I change this:

```
...
...
...

// check if user is logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $allowed = false;
}

// Check the user privileges
if( !( current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce_orders' ) || current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) && !isset( $_GET['my-account'] ) ) {
    $allowed = false;
}

// User call from my-account page
if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') && isset( $_GET['my-account'] ) ) {
    // Only for single orders!
    if ( count( $order_ids ) > 1 ) {
        $allowed = false;
    }

    // Check if current user is owner of order IMPORTANT!!!
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'view_order', $order_ids[0] ) ) {
        $allowed = false;
    }
}
```

to this:

```
// check if user is logged in
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $allowed = false;
}

// // Check the user privileges
// if( !( current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce_orders' ) || current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders' ) ) && !isset( $_GET['my-account'] ) ) {
//  $allowed = false;
// }
// 
// // User call from my-account page
// if ( !current_user_can('manage_options') && isset( $_GET['my-account'] ) ) {
//  // Only for single orders!
//  if ( count( $order_ids ) > 1 ) {
//      $allowed = false;
//  }
// 
//  // Check if current user is owner of order IMPORTANT!!!
//  if ( ! current_user_can( 'view_order', $order_ids[0] ) ) {
//      $allowed = false;
//  }
// }
```

Comment: Have you considered asking the original plugin author to add a filter for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @kero noted, your best option is to contact the developer and ask if they are open to including an appropriate hook - what you need is a filter to allow customization for the value of `$allowed`.

However, barring that, one potential (albeit not perfect) solution is to ignore updates for the plugin.  You can do that as follows:

```
function filter_plugin_updates( $value ) {
    unset( $value->response['some_plugin/some_plugin.php'] );
    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'site_transient_update_plugins', 'filter_plugin_updates' );
```

Then you would not get update notifications or automatic updates for the plugin.  That would allow you to re-apply your change manually to the update and handle things manually.

Obviously, if you can get the developer onboard with a filter hook, you're better off.  But if you're handling things manually, this keeps you from blowing out your customization unintentionally.